# Recuperando item de um array mongoDB usando C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Bom dia,
Estou com dificuldades ao recuperar item de um array dentro de um documento Mongo usando C#. Abaixo o exemplo de um documento:

```
{"_id":"5e1374ae38fa7026b88d4dc8",
"Estacao":"NomeDaEstacao",
"Diretorio":[{"Caminho":"c:",
"TmoMonDiretorio":50,
"UltimoMonDiretorio":"2020-01-06T17:55:58.370Z"}],
"Habilitado":true}
```

Caminho é um objeto de Diretorio; Estacao,TmoMonDiretorio,UltimoMonDiretorio e Habilitado são objetos de Configuracao. Ainda dentro de Configuração existe um List Diretorio.
Estou conseguindo Recuperar estacao e habilitado com o método abaixo e salvar em suas respectivas variáveis, mas TmoMonDiretorio, UltimoMonDiretorio não esta encontrando, segue o código.

```
private Diretorio RecDiretorio(BsonDocument doc)
{
 if(doc !=null)
   {
     Diretorio diret = new Diretorio(doc.GetValue("Caminho").AsString;
     return diret
   }
   return null;
}

 private Configuracao RecCfgMonitoramento(BsonDocument doc)
        {

            if (doc != null)
            {

                List<Diretorio> dir = new List<Diretorio>();
                if (doc.Contains("Diretorio"))
                {
                    BsonArray diretorioBD = doc.GetValue("Diretorio").AsBsonArray;
                    foreach (BsonValue diretorio in diretorioBD)
                        dir.Add(RecCfgDiretorio(diretorio.AsBsonDocument));
                }
 Configuracao cfgMonitoramento = new Configuracao(
                    doc.GetValue("Estacao").AsString,
                    dir,                    
                    (float)doc.GetValue("TmoMonDiretorio").AsInt32,
                    doc.Contains("UltimoDiretorio") ?    doc.GetValue("UltimoMonDiretorio").ToLocalTime() : DateTime.MinValue,                                       
                    doc.GetValue("Habilitado").AsBoolean);
                // Cria filtro.
                return cfgMonitoramento;                
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Classe Configuração

```
public class Configuracao{      

        public string Estacao { get; set; }

        public List<Diretorio> Diretorios { get; set; }

        public float TmoMonDiretorios { get; set; } // (segundos)

        public DateTime UltimoMonDiretorios { get; set; }

        public bool Habilitado { get; set; }

 public Configuracao() : this("", new List<Diretorio>(), 0.0F, true) { }

public Configuracao(string estacao, 
            List<Diretorio> diretorio, 
            float tmoMonDiretorios, 
            DateTime ultimoMonDiretorios,            
            bool habilitado)
        {
            Estacao = estacao;
            Diretorios = diretorio;            
            TmoMonDiretorios = tmoMonDiretorios;
            UltimoMonDiretorios = ultimoMonDiretorios;            
            Habilitado = habilitado;
        }
}
```

Concluindo, preciso recuperar os dados de TmoMonDiretorio e UltimoMonDiretorio, quando debugo o código estacao,caminho e habilitado esta dando certo, teria como me ajudar?

Edit:

```
public class Diretorio
    {

        public string Caminho{ get; set; }
        public long EspacoTotal{ get; set; }
        public long EspacoDisponivel{ get; set; }
        public double PercentualDisponivel
        {
            get { return 100.0 * EspacoDisponivel / EspacoTotal; }
        }
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // -- Construtores
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Construtor padrão.
        /// </summary>
        public Diretorio() : this("") { }

        public Diretorio(string caminho, long espacoTotal, long espacoDisponivel) 
        {
            Caminho = caminho;
            EspacoTotal = espacoTotal;
            EspacoDisponivel = espacoDisponivel;
        }
}
```

Comment: Poderia incluir o código de `Diretorio`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há uma diferença entre o objeto do Mongo e a sua classe. No Mongo, as propriedades `TmoMonDiretorio` e `UltimoMonDiretorio` estão em `Diretorio` (que apesar de ter o nome no singular, é uma lista). Para corrigir o problema é necessário verificar se as propriedades pertencem à classe `Diretorio` ou `Configuracao`.

- Caso pertençam à `Configuracao`, é necessário corrigir os dados no Mongo.
- Caso pertençam à `Diretorio`, é preciso alterar a classe, passando as propriedades para `Diretorio` e preencher os valores no método `RecDiretorio`, no lugar de usar o construtor de `Configuracao`.

Também cabe ressaltar que não é necessário ter todo esse código. O próprio driver do Mongo para C# faz a desserialização do objeto.

Ex:

```cs
var colecao = database.GetCollection<Entidade>("entidades");
var filtro = Query<Entidade>.EQ(e => e.Id, id);
var entidade = collection.FindOne(filtro);
```

Onde `Entidade` seria a sua classe e `entidades` a coleção no Mongo. No exemplo acima, é feito a busca de `Entidade` pelo seu `id`.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, a minha solução foi realmente tirar os dados TmoMonDiretorio e UltimoMonDiretorio de dentro da lista de Diretório e deixa-los apenas como objetos de Configuração.